# Access denied for user 'awarn2'@'127.0.0.1' -- Can't connect to database

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have some problems connecting my scripts to the database.

I have a web-server running with apache and mariadb. My website works perfectly fine but some other scripts are getting a permission denied error.

```
2:45:50    71 Connect   awarn2@127.0.0.1 as anonymous on awarn
      71 Connect    Access denied for user 'awarn2'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

I had a username and password for that script so maybe there was a mistake in the password I thought. Then I tried it with the root user.

```
2:46:07    94 Connect   root@127.0.0.1 as anonymous on awarn
       94 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

I can login to phpmyadmin with the same password. So the password cant be wrong.

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Are the scripts located on the same server?

Comment: xD yes they are

Comment: And it doesnt matter if I choose localhost or 127.0.0.1 because I do have the same error with both.

Comment: Are you able to telnet to the server? Perform a connection test there.

Comment: `telnet 127.0.0.1
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@GPR0078:~# telnet localhost
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Comment: hold on, do you have everything (including apache, mariadb, phpmyadmin) running on your local machine?

Comment: no its an external I did this on my server
I can connect to my server and my website is running too. The problem is that other scripts are not able to connect to the server. And yes these scripts are located on my server too

Comment: ok even a facepalm wont be enough for that xD 
`skip-name-resolve`
I dont know how that command found its way into my config but that was it that caused that problem